# Reliable multicast libraries

Tags: multicast, jgroups, reliable-multicast

Thinking to implement Reliable Multicast for a Desktop Application.
Gone through JRMS and found that there is no proper documentation for it.
Is JRMS still in use?? Or otherwise how JGroups can be effective for Reliable Multicast?
Is there any other reliable multicast libraries available, which is available for many languages like Java, C++, etc.,

Comment: I need multicast as well, but for server-node notification&syncing. I am considering between JGroups and separate MQ server. JGroups would result in less complicated architecture as no additional server would be required, but not sure how well JGroups behaves, especially in use cases where nodes might come and go.